# coverting a tibbles data into different format

Tags: r

i am given the following data:

```
temperatures <- tibble(
month = c("January", "January", "May", "May", "September", "September"), statistic_type = c( "max", "min", "max", "min", "max", "min"),
value = c(19, 11, 13, 6, 13, 6)
)
```

and need to convert it into a different format to get this result:
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+reshape+long+to+wide

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_wider(temperatures, names_from = "statistic_type", values_from = "value")` should do it. See the linked FAQ for more explanation and other options (though I'd strongly recommend sticking with the `tidyr` package for now)